# how to handle multiple delete and displaying 1 message using delete service in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, service

[When i check all lists in table, and press delete button, A DELETE SERVICE will be called.(Using AngularJS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Mtv.png)

> Problem is, i am using a loop, and on successful delete and unsuccessful delete, i am getting alert multiple times.(No. of selection times)

And its not working properly, if place it out of loop because its Async Task.

Here is the code,

This is a controller which initiates a service.

```
        $scope.confirmAction = function() {
        var costsToDelete = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.objects, function(cost) {
            if (cost.selected == true) {
                costsToDelete.push(cost);
            }
        });
        $scope.deleted = true;
        //need to put confirmation dialog here.
        //URL: specific to timesheet deletion. it will be prefixed with constant url
        var delRequestUrl = URLs.costsUrl + '/';
        deleteService.deleteRecord($scope.objects, costsToDelete, delRequestUrl);
    };
```

**This is a service.**

```
.service('deleteService', ['dataService', 'Constant.urls', 'Constants','$q','alerts',function(dataService, URLs, Constants, $q, alerts) {
var deleteService = {}; 
deleteService.deleteRecord = function(records, listOfRecordsToDelete, url) {
    while (listOfRecordsToDelete.length > 0) {
        var recordToBeDeleted = listOfRecordsToDelete.pop();
        var index = listOfRecordsToDelete.indexOf(recordToBeDeleted);
        var delRequestUrl = url + recordToBeDeleted.id;

        var result = dataService.deleteObject(delRequestUrl);

        result.success(function(data) {

        Alert('success');

            records.splice(index, 1);
        });

        result.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            dataService.handleError(status,data);

        Alert('error');

        });
    }
};
return deleteService;   }])
```

**I need a result like: Alert should display only once.
If all items are successfully deleted, then success or failure message.**

Comment: Try this 

`records.splice(index, 1);
if(!!!records.length) {
    Alert('success');
}`

Comment: Why dont you just create a boolean bit `var status= false;//default value` to `true` inside success callback handler and `false` inside error callback handler, so once all calls are complete based on this bit you can alert success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create a boolean bit `var status= false;//default value` to `true` inside success callback handler and `false` inside error callback handler,

so once all calls are complete based on this bit you can alert success or failure

**Angular JS Code:**

```
.service('deleteService', ['dataService', 'Constant.urls', 'Constants','$q','alerts',function(dataService, URLs, Constants, $q, alerts) {
var statusBit = false; // status tracker
var deleteService = {}; 
deleteService.deleteRecord = function(records, listOfRecordsToDelete, url) {
while (listOfRecordsToDelete.length > 0) {
    var recordToBeDeleted = listOfRecordsToDelete.pop();
    var index = listOfRecordsToDelete.indexOf(recordToBeDeleted);
    var delRequestUrl = url + recordToBeDeleted.id;

    var result = dataService.deleteObject(delRequestUrl);

    result.success(function(data) {

   // Alert('success');
   statusBit = true;

        records.splice(index, 1);
    });

    result.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        dataService.handleError(status,data);

    //Alert('error');
    statusBit = false;

    });
    if(statusBit){
        Alert('success');  //console.log('successfully deleted');
    }
    else {
        Alert('error'); // console.log('error while deleting');
    }
};
return deleteService;   }])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .service('deleteService', ['dataService', 'Constant.urls', 'Constants','$q','alerts',function(dataService, URLs, Constants, $q, alerts) {
var deleteService = {}; 
deleteService.deleteRecord = function(records, listOfRecordsToDelete, url) {
    var overallResult = true;
    while (listOfRecordsToDelete.length > 0) {
        var recordToBeDeleted = listOfRecordsToDelete.pop();
        var index = listOfRecordsToDelete.indexOf(recordToBeDeleted);
        var delRequestUrl = url + recordToBeDeleted.id;

        var result = dataService.deleteObject(delRequestUrl);

        result.success(function(data) {

            records.splice(index, 1);
        });

        result.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            dataService.handleError(status,data);

            overallResult = false ;

        });
    }
};
return deleteService;   }])
```

Comment: based on the overallResult you can popup the message, out of the while loop if its false only.